# CentOS yum 'No package gnuradio available'

Tags: gnuradio

I'm installing GNU Radio and following the instruction [here](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/InstallingGR#Linux)

But everytime I try to do `sudo yum install gnuradio`, it says

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.cdnetworks.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.cdnetworks.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.cdnetworks.com
Setting up Install Process
No package gnuradio available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

It's a fresh installed CentOS 6.5 and I've never edited CentOS yum repository information. What's wrong with gnuradio? They've removed the package from yum repository?

In their website, they provide several ways to install it including `PyBOMBS`. But I prefer `yum`. Building from source is somewhat bothering me so it's the last thing I will try.

Comment: For a while, I got `build-gnuradio` script and am running it.

Answer (score 0):

By default CentOS does not include all the repositories needed by gnuradio and its dependencies.

You additionally need to configure/add at least RPMForge and Epel for your CentOS.

References:

http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-f0c3ecee3dbb407e4eed79a56ec0ae92d1398e01

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x

This is what I was told, but I have not yet tested this so cannot say is is correct for sure.